# Googlemap Javascript api, adding listener, variable scope

Tags: javascript

```
var marker = []
var info = []
function callback(results, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for(var i =0; i<results.length; i++) {
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position : results[i].geometry.location, map:map});
            marker[i].setLabel(results[i].name);
            info[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content:results[i].name });
            info[i].open(map,marker[i]);//works well.
            marker[i].addListener('click', function() {
                info[i].open(map,marker[i]);//error, info[i] is undefined
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with variable info[i].
There are two commented lines.
First one shows the info window well. 
But second line emits an error(info[i] is undefined).
Why is that?

Comment: The variable 'i' will equal `results.length` by the time a click happens. This is a common issue with loops and async events. You can try using `let i =0` instead of `var` if you don't need to support old browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works beautiful now. Could you explain what 'let i=0' does a little more? Prevent async?

Comment: The reason `var` causes problems is that it's scoped to the outside function. So every time through the loop the same variable gets reused. This is a problem with async things because that same variable gets changed before the async function can use it. `let` scopes the variable to the enclosing block so each time through the loop you get a fresh variable.